# How to achieve AND/OR in JQL query

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to create a JQL query with multiple ANDs and then the last two fields (Fix Version and Epic) I want results returned if either of them match, but I'm struggling. This is what I currently have:

`project = Project AND status in ("status 1", "status 2", "status 3") AND creator in ("creator 1, "creator 2", "creator 3") AND (fixVersion != "Version 1" or fixVersion is EMPTY) AND "Epic Link" is EMPTY ORDER BY fixVersion ASC, created DESC`

This seems to work correctly. But, if a given issue doesn't have a Fix Version and I add one, that issue is removed from the list even if it has no Epic Link. What I want is it to remain in the list if it still doesn't have an Epic link.

I tried changing it to OR "Epic Link" but this then seemed to ignore the rest of the query and just gave me everything without an Epic Link.

Can anyone see how to get what I want?

Comment: Your problem is that you need to use `( )` in the right places ... That's all.
Just a logic error.
Maybe using the "Basic" setting will help: manually compose the query with the mouse, then click "Advanced" and you'll see the query you need (auto-generated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your issue, as far as I could deduce from your question:
Add `( )` and fix the logic error (OR, not AND!)

```
project = Project
AND status in ("status 1", "status 2", "status 3")
AND creator in ("creator 1, "creator 2", "creator 3")
AND ( fixVersion != "Version 1"
      OR fixVersion is EMPTY
      OR "Epic Link" is EMPTY )

ORDER BY fixVersion ASC, created DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave it a go but it's not given me quite what I wanted (probably my poor initial explanation!).

It's returning issues that don't have an Epic but do have a Fix Version of "Version 1". Whereas I don't want any issues returned that have this Fix Version.

Comment: i.e.

Fix Version = "Version 1" and Epic Link is "Epic 1" - DO NOT RETURN
Fix Version = "Version 1" and Epic Link is EMPTY - DO NOT RETURN
Fix Version  = "Version 2" and Epic Link is "Epic 1" - RETURN
Fix Version  = "Version 2" and Epic Link is EMPTY - RETURN
Fix Version  = EMPTY and Epic Link is "Epic 1" - RETURN
Fix Version  = EMPTY and Epic Link is EMPTY - RETURN

Comment: Ugh, don't know how to make that look nice in a comment, sorry!

Comment: Hello Jon, I edited my answer. Based on your comment, I think you don't really care about fixVersion or Epic Link, as long as the fixVersion is not "Version 1".
So that's what I changed in my suggested fix, if it is what you needed, please accept. If not, I'll try again ;)

Comment: Thanks Guillius, I realised I made a mistake in my comment with the scenarios. I should have said: Fix Version = "Version 1" and Epic Link is EMPTY - RETURN. Sorry!!

Comment: Hi @Jon, I edited again. I hope it's what you need!

Comment: Thanks Guillius, almost. But we did get there. It was excluding anything where Fix Version = EMPTY and by including "or fixVersion is EMPTY" inside the final bracket it's given me what I want. Thanks for your help on this :-)

Comment: If you want to edit your comment I'll happily accept the answer :-)

Comment: I'm happy you got it working, and done!